# add thread.sleep if port receive did not message in Serial Port c#

Tags: c#-4.0

ih have code send receive data through serial port like below :

```
 serialPort1.WriteLine(item);
                Thread.Sleep(10000);
                sRecv = serialPort1.ReadExisting().ToString();
```

while sending the data and then receive the data after Thread.sleep 10 seconds, but the problem when Port did not receive the data after 10 seconds, how is it to add Thread.sleep if in the next 10 seconds if no data is received

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe do a test to see if there's data available to be read:

```
while(serialPort1.BytesToRead == 0)
{
    Thread.Sleep(10000);
}
sRecv = serialPort1.ReadExisting();
```

BTW you do not need to call `ToString` because `ReadExisting` already returns a string.

EDIT:

To stop after 60 seconds:

```
int timeOut = 60000;
int waitedTime = 0;
int waitInterval = 10000;
while (serialPort1.BytesToRead == 0 && waitedTime < timeOut)
{
    Thread.Sleep(waitInterval);
    waitedTime += waitInterval;
}
sRecv = serialPort1.ReadExisting();
```

Comment: @MuhammadIbnuSaefullah yw :)

Comment: one again, how make Time Out if more than 60 second :-)

Comment: @MuhammadIbnuSaefullah, you mean you want to stop sleeping after 60 seconds?

Comment: yes i want stop after 60 second if port receive did not receive message.

Comment: i have Bytes in (SerialPort1.BytesRead), but how to clear Bytes from SerialPort? i tried this code : serialPort1.DiscardInBuffer();
                                           serialPort1.DiscardOutBuffer();
but not works...
please help me :-)

Comment: @MuhammadIbnuSaefullah, you should ask another question for your new problem.

Comment: im sorry I bother you again, but i need to help in case serial port, this my case, please...
this my question
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32680543/how-to-waiting-reply-until-60-second-in-serial-port-c-sharp